# Computing the spin cobordism groups of a CW complex from its cohomology groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cobordism

It is shown in Conner and Floyd's book "Differentiable periodic maps", Theorem 14.2, that the oriented bordism group of a CW-complex $X$ can be computed by

$\Omega_p(X) = \sum_{q = 0}^p H_q(X;\Omega_{p-q})$ modulo odd torsion,

where $\Omega_\ast$ denote the oriented bordism groups of a point. This is apparently due to the fact that the oriented bordism spectral sequence is trivial modulo odd torsion.

Question: Is the analogous statement for spin bordism groups true?

Comment: That is because $MSO$ is a wedge of Eilenberg--Maclane spectra when localised at 2; equivalently its $k$-invariants are all odd torsion. This is not the case for $MSpin$: for example, the work of Anderson--Brown--Peterson shows that many copies of $ko$ split off when localised at 2.